# Meteor + React component - unable to reference jQuery

Tags: jquery, meteor, reactjs

I am trying to migrate a React component, written outside of Meteor, to run inside Meteor.  The problem I have is that jQuery ($) is not defined.  I fully understand that the use of jQuery is not necessary in a lot of cases and is even frowned upon within React.  That being said, Meteor currently installs jQuery by default.  Being able to use jQuery for animations will help me overcome a limitation of React's ReactTransitionGroup and ReactCSSTransitionGroup components.  I can not simply add a link to jQuery CDN because that would cause jQuery to be loaded twice!  Once from the CDN and once inside Meteor.

My problem is that I don't know how to access Meteor's jQuery from within a React component.

Here is a snippet of one of my components:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.slideDirection !== this.props.slideDirection) {
        this.setState({ slideDirection: nextProps.slideDirection })
        var $el = $(this.getDOMNode());
        if (nextProps.slideDirection.trim() === 'down') { console.log('= down'); } else { console.log('!= down'); }
        switch (nextProps.slideDirection.trim()) {
            case 'up':
                $el.slideUp('animationDuration: 400');
                break;
            case 'down':
                $el.slideDown('animationDuration: 400');
                break;
            default:

        }
    }
},
```

I have really struggled with this all weekend.  I "really" want to be able to use jQuery in this case for the animation effect.  I am trying to animate the DIV height expansion along with visibility of the body text.  This is easily achieved with jQuery's slideup and slidedown.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using 1.2.0.2? I suppose you already added the `jquery` package and tried `$.fn.jquery` in your console, right?

Comment: Radu, see answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Make sure you even have jquery added to your project.

```
$ meteor add jquery
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct!  I assumed that jQuery was bundled with the Meteor sample (which it is when you create your Meteor app with "Meteor create".  But, this sample app had jQuery removed.  Adding jquery manually solved the problem.  Very good!  Thank you!!!